# Chrome Extensions: Using getElementById

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Based on some other code I found from this site (This Question here - [Get URL and save it | Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797853/get-url-and-save-it-chrome-extension))
I was wondering on how to display the URL of a current page in a input box. My coding is below

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = tab.url;
      });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="links">
<div id="currentLink">Getting Current URL...</div>
<input type="text" id="currentLink" value="Loading...">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(I've cut some features out).
But my question is, how can I get the URL to display in the input box, it displays when I use "div id" but not when I use "input id" any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `value` attribute of inputs.

```
document.getElementById('currentLink').value = tab.url;
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this at first, didn't work, copied the entire code, changed the ID worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I don't mean to sound stupid, but how do I do that? I'm new here

Comment: To the left of the answer below the down arrow should be a checkmark.