# How to pass a saved Javascript variable in a Chrome extension to a Google App Engine App?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple bookmarking app that I am developing to learn Google App Engine. At this point I copy and paste the url into http://ting-1.appspot.com/submit which has a form that has a url field. Since this is cumbersome I thought of adding a chrome extension. I just changed the [hello world example](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) so that now I get the url of the tab with this code [(as explained here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797853/get-url-and-save-it-chrome-extension/2797972#2797972):

```
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", windowLoaded, false);
    function windowLoaded() {
      chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = tab.url;
        tabUrl = tab.url;
      });
    }
document.write(tabUrl)
  </script>
```

How do I pass `tabUrl` to http://ting-1.appspot.com/submit?

Thanks!

**Update**

`background.html` that I used as adapted from [Mohamed Mansour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704394/how-to-pass-a-saved-javascript-variable-in-a-chrome-extension-to-a-google-app-eng/7705147#7705147):

```
<script>
    //React when a browser action's icon is clicked.
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        //this gets the url and the title
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            tabUrl = tab.url
            tabTitle = tab.title

        //this posts the data to the bookmarking app 
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("url", tabUrl);
        formData.append("title", tabTitle);
        formData.append("pitch", "this is a note");
        formData.append("user_tag_list", "tag1, tag2");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest");
        xhr.send(formData);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use normal XHR (XMLHttpRequest) request. I would place that in your [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html). Follow the example here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest. I believe you want to submit data as well, so don't forget that. I think you wanted a POST request too. From the example on MDC, you can relate it this way:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submit");
xhr.send(formData);
```

Make sure you have the URL in your [manifest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) for getting permissions to do that request.

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  " http://ting-1.appspot.com/submit"
],
```

Comment: @ Mohamed Mansour: Thanks for your answer. This worked perfectly. Additional thanks for the link to the `XMLHttpRequest` tutorial. Now I want to add a callback function to indicate that the submit was successful. I am reading the Asynchronous request section https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Example:_Asynchronous_request but if you have any practical advice about how to add a callback function in my situation, that would be helpful too, or I will post another question later if necessary. I updated the question with the code that I used. Thanks again.