# How to animate chrome extension icon in a callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

This is a follow up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704394/how-to-pass-a-saved-javascript-variable-in-a-chrome-extension-to-a-google-app-eng) about using `XMLHttpRequest()` to post to my bookmarking app. When I receive the `status 200 OK` I want to indicate somehow with a change in the extension icon that the request was successful. I created another icon `success_icon.png` with reverse colors and I am trying to make the new icon replace the original icon and fade into original icon. I understand that this will be inside my callback function but I don't understand how? Here's my `background.html`. Thanks!

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    tabId = tab.id;
    tabUrl = tab.url
    tabTitle = tab.title

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("url", tabUrl);
formData.append("title", tabTitle);
formData.append("pitch", "this is a note");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200)
            console.log("request 200-OK")
        else
        console.log("Error", xhr.statusText);
    }
};        
xhr.send(formData);
```

**Update**

Code adapted from [eduardocereto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730577/how-to-animate-chrome-extension-icon-in-a-callback-function/7731008#7731008) but `setTimeout` is not working properly:

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    console.log("request 200-OK");
    //chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: '/success_icon.png'});
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );

    function resetBadge() {
        setTimeout (chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "" } ), 10000);
    }
    resetBadge()

}
```

Comment: Well changing icon is easy but "fade into" - not so much. Do you know how to do it in pure javascript?

Comment: @serg: ok, can you give me some clues about how I can change the icon, say for a few seconds, and then go back to the original icon. Because I don't yet understand how I can do that. I'll try fading after that. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the code inside the setTimeout in your example is not delayed. It's executed right away and the return of that execution is executed after the timeout

Comment: is there a way to do this with a GIF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the icon dynamically you can call:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: '/path/img/success_icon.png'})
```

To create the fade effect would not be so easy, but you can use a `<canvas>` element instead of static image to set the Icon. Then you can probably animate the canvas the way you want.

Checkout this article on how to load an image into the canvas and change it's opacity:

[How to change the opacity (alpha, transparency) of an element in a canvas element after it has been drawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359537/how-to-change-the-opacity-alpha-transparency-of-an-element-in-a-canvas-element)

API Reference:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon

To use the `setBadgeText` with `setTimeout` you should do this:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );
setTimeout(function () {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "" } );
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also tried `setBadgeText` and that works fine. Then, I use `setTimeout` to reset the Badge to `""` but I couldn't make `setTimeout` delay enough. I have it set to `10000` and still it just blinks. What am I doing wrong. I updated the question with the code. Thanks again.

Comment: For me browserAction is undefined in chrome. Can you please help ?

Answer (score 1):

I got here looking for a way to attract some attention to my browser action extension...

So here's some handy code to flash the badge:

```
function flashBadge(message, times, interval) {
    flash();
    function flash() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (times == 0) {
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: message});
                return;
            }
            if (times % 2 == 0) {
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: message});
            } else {
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: ""});
            }
            times--;
            flash();
        }, interval);
    }
}
```