# Communication between ContentScript.js and Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I simply want to send the current tab url to my extension:

Following is my manifest.json

```
{
 "name": "DocUrlExtention",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "The first extension that I made.",
 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
 "content_scripts": [
 {
  "matches": ["http://*/*"],
  "js": ["contentscript.js"]
 }
 ]}
```

Following is my contentscript.js

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({url: window.location.href}, function(response) {
   console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

Following is my popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>

<script>
    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
                    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                    "from the extension");
      });
</script>

<!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
<!--<script src="popup.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">Doc Id:</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't see anything in console. I am new to Chrome extensions.

Comment: People are finding my related answer helpful which provides some info about Chrome Extensions that I learned spending way too much time learning about them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920473/chrome-extension-background-page-html-not-working/19487091#19487091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest file contains [`"manifest_version": 2,`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#manifest_version), which enables the [Content Security Policy](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html). By default, [Inline JavaScript will not be executed](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H3-1). And, there is [no way to relax the CSP such that inline JavaScript is allowed](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H2-3).

You've got two options:

1. Remove `"manifest_version": 2` (which disabled the default CSP).
2. Move the inline JavaScript to an external file.

The second method is recommended, and *also suggested in your code...*

```
...
<!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
<!--<script src="popup.js"></script>-->
</head>
...
```

PS. The Dev tools for the pop-up can be opened by **right-clicking** on the browser action icon, and selecting the last option, ["Inspect popup"](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup).