# Chrome extension background page html not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to understand chrome background pages. I managed to get background.js script running after cannibalizing on the of examples and it pops up with an alert box every time a user visits a page. However, when I take the same script and move it to a background.html file, I cannot seem to get the file to execute.

I have updated the the manifest file to a page (instead of script) and the extension loads fine. I have also tried playing around with either having the javascript in a script tag directly in the body or in a function as it is now that is called onload on the body or in the head.

Perhaps I don't understand the concept of what a background.html page is used for in a Chrome extension?

Manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Testing Extension",
  "version": "0.2",
  "background": { "pages": ["background.html"] },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "https://mail.google.com/*", "http://*/*, https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Do some action",
    "icons": ["icon.png"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "web_accessible_resources": ["injectImage.js", "background.html"]
}
```

injectImage.js

```
alert('Got Here');
'use strict';   
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "injectImage.js"});
});

    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: [0, 200, 0, 100]});

    var i = 0;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String(i)});
        i++;
    }, 10);
```

background.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="injectImage.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
</body>
</html>
```

currently this code doesn't seem to do anything other than put an icon in the top right corner.

Comment: Inline scripts (and inline event handlers) are not executed due to the Content Security Policy. To solve it, read the documentation of the [CSP](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H2-3).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communication between ContentScript.js and Chrome Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416594/communication-between-contentscript-js-and-chrome-extension)

Comment: I read through the CSP. I moved the js to a separate file and put the script tags in the head and removed the init() wrapper. However, even if I change to manifest version 1 it still is not running. Is this because the code above doesn't have access to the browser button?

Comment: Edit your question to show your current code. Your original code could never have worked in the first place, because your script block contains a `src` attribute.

Comment: Current code has been updated

Comment: I think that you wanted to use `hrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:` **"content.js"** `});` instead of `injectImage.js`

Comment: The naming of the script shouldn't affect how the script interacts though as long as I am consistent in naming, correct? I tried changing it all to content.js (content.js was just another file I was playing with), and still si not working...code updated above again to remove the content.js

Comment: I was referring to the fact that your background page includes `injectImage.js`, which, in turn, executes the *same file* as a content script. That's not going to work.

Answer (score 25):

Your **background is only one page and acts like a local server** that can send and receive data between the `content_scripts` and `default_popup` or other extension pages.

For anyone starting out, look at each example's manifest version, which is defined in manifest.json.  Version 2 has stricter security policies and inline javascript is invalid so copying sample v1 code and pasting it into background.html will not work anymore.  All scripts need to be in an external file that can be included in an HTML file using the `src` attribute like `<script src="main.js"></script>`

My understanding is that you have four commonly used components for a basic extension:

1. DOM of the tab being viewed which can **only be accessed by `content_scripts`**
2. **content_scripts** is an array of javascript files identified in manifest.json that are sequentially injected directly into the tab's DOM.  Apparently the JS variables and functions from the tab and your content_scripts cannot interact.
3. **One background HTML page** which Chrome either generates by concatenating an array of scripts **OR** is defined as one page, commonly named background.html.
4. `{"browser_action" : {"default_popup" : "popup.html"}}` is an optional user interface defined in manifest.json that is displayed when someone clicks your extension icon.  The popup has no way to reach the tab's DOM so if the tab's content matters then it must be requested using Chrome messages like `chrome.extension.sendMessage`

Your background is defined either as one or more `scripts`:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```

Or as a `page`:

```
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
```

If you want to find out what is happening inside of the background then you can use console.log but in order to inspect the output you have to launch the inspector from the Extensions page.  You can even see that the background file is always named "_generated_background_page.html".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @Dylan! I'm wondering, what is the usages for background:page:"background.html"? While action_popup is a popup which is associated with the extension's button, the background page is not quite clear when it comes to html (ok, for js it's more like a server which makese sense). Is there a way to present that "background" html to a user?

Comment: Glad it helped, sorry I don't have more for you

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your manifest file. Including a background page should look like this:

```
"background": {"page": "background.html"}
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I thought that the syntax used in the question should be valid for using multiple background pages?

Answer (score 2):

OR you can directly define js instead of defining a background page and referencing a script file in it (Inline scripts are not allowed as per Content Security Policy (CSP))

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

### For version 3

[background pages are replaced by `service_workers` in MV3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/#api_checklist)

> Replace `background.page` or `background.scripts` with `background.service_worker` in manifest.json.

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more gotcha not mentioned here. Doing `<script src="myscript"/>` doesn't work :P, you have to type it out completely with `<script src="myscript"></script>`. Took me a bit to figure that out.