# how can i fire up contentscript

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i got a simple question
i have these3 files 
popup.html :

```
<script>
    function buttonClicked(button) 
    {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({command:button.id});
    }
</script>
    <input style="width:100%" type="button" value="Click me" id="click" onclick="buttonClicked(this)"/><br/>
```

background.html :

```
<script>
    function processRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) 
    {
        alert('hi');
        sendResponse({});
    }
    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(processRequest);
</script>
```

and contentscript.js

```
s = document.getElementsByClassName('st');
if (s[0].innerText != '') { 
st = new Array(); 
for (i = 0;i<s.length;i++) {
    st[i] = s[i].innerText;
}
chrome.extension.sendMessage({"message" : st}, function(response) {});
}
```

i would like to fire up the contentscript each time i click on the button in the popup page be cause somehow the script in the contentscript dosnt work neither or background.html nor on popup.html?

thank you

Comment: Thanks to manifest version 2 and the CSP. Solution: Move the JavaScript to an external file. Possible duplicate of [Port error while changing chrome extension from manifest v1 to v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913575/port-error-while-changing-chrome-extension-from-manifest-v1-to-v2)

Comment: if manifest 2 caused this error can i just use the version 1?!

Comment: Manifest v1 support is being phased out. Why don't you use the solution I presented? It's the recommended way to get your extension to work.

Comment: well that dosnt really solve my problem, all what i want is to execute the contentscript when i click on the button in the popup page thats it, because when i execute it from the background page or the popup page i cant really get to the current tab elemnts.*

Comment: I guess that you didn't understand my other comment and answer. The solution is to move the inline JavaScript to an external file, and refer to that external file using `<script src>`. Hope that you understand it now. If not, here's a similar answer, but targetting pop-ups: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10417745/938089

Comment: so in my case i put the background script into a external file, then just call it? how it will be executed?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've attempted to explain the solution and why to use it in the comments, three times. Since you don't understand it, I'll explain it again with references to your code:

#### Popup

- Move the inline script to an external file, say `popup.js`.
- Delete the inline event listener, and also move it to `popup.js`.

#### `popup.js`

```
function buttonClicked(button) {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({command: button.id});
}
document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', function() {
    buttonClicked(this);
});
```

#### `popup.html`

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<input style="width:100%" type="button" value="Click me" id="click"><br>
```

If you test the previous code, you'll notice that it does not work. That's because the contents of `popup.js` is executed before the button (which occurs *after* the `<script src>` is created. This can be solved in two ways (use either method, but not both):

- Recommended: Place `<script src="popup.js"></script>` before the closing `</body>` tag in `popup.html`. Then, you're certain that all elements do exist when the script is executed.
- Alternative: Wrap the event listener call in a `DOMContentLoaded` event:

  ```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      document.getElementByUd('click').addEventListener( ... );
  });
  ```

### Background page.

For a more thorough explanation on the available options, see the middle of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913575/port-error-while-changing-chrome-extension-from-manifest-v1-to-v2).

- Modify the manifest file, use `"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]}`.
- Rename `background.html` to `background.js`, and remove `<script>` and `</script>` from the file.

Comment: so i have done as u said, it kinda work, but it didnt actually work, i mean the script works ... but not the way i wanted, i wanted the popup.js gets access to the page elements ! not the popup.html elements ... like the content script, when a page is fully loaded, i can get to the current page elements

Comment: ok, i think i found a solution, is to use executeScript and execute the contentScript.js in executeScript. 
function hello(){ 
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
        code:   "s = document.getElementsByClassName('st');" + 
    "st = s[0].innerText;"+
    "chrome.extension.sendMessage({\"message\":st});"})
}; 
but is there another way other that executeScript??

Comment: @yassine_hell Yes, you can inject a content script via the manifest file, which defines a message listener. Then, use [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendMessage) to send a message, and use the `sendResponse` callback to send back *JSON-serializable* data (no nodes, but strings!). But your current solution looks OK, because it only uses content scripts when necessary.

Comment: ok thanks for your help, and im sorry for ur time ... just started with google extensions :s ...