# Loading jQuery into chrome-extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm trying my first step into the magical world of Chrome Extensions.
Now i've build up my manifest trying to load jquery.

```
{
    "name": "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "First try",
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["chrome-extension://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "popup.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Click me!"
    }
}
```

Actually trying to reload the extension tell me that the "matches" do not match a valid schema.

But that's not all. To get over it, i've tried just changing the "matches" value to `*://*/*` and reload.
Well, the extension seems to load correctly but seems like the jquery is not loaded due to the error i can get from the popup.js that just tell me

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Actually the HTML is just:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Extension</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" src="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

The popup.js code just do this:

```
$("#test").html("Foo!");
```

Comment: did you mean `$("#test").html("Foo!");` instead of `$.('#test')`?

Comment: Yes. That was a distraction error. I'm going to edit the question.
Shame on me.

Of course the error is now a more indicative "$ is not defined"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Content scripts will **never** run in the context of an extension. The correct way to load scripts in your browser action popup is by including it in your code. Let your manifest file be:

```
{
    "name": "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Click me!"
    }
}
```

And `popup.html`:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

Comment: Changing like you suggest, give me the following error:
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following `Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".`

Comment: @theCrius Your real code contains inline scripts (either `<script>....</script>` or event listeners, these are explicitly forbidden by the [Content security policy](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10417745/938089. To solve it, move the code to an external file.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: By "event listener", I mean "inline event listener", eg. `<body onload="...">` or `<button onclick="...">`.

Comment: That's weird because actually i've just edited the popup.html as you suggest and the error is still here.
There is nothing in the html page. except the empty `<div id="test">`

Anyway, now i can see both the js loaded correctly in the console.
The error appear in the html that confirm your observation.

Comment: @theCrius Have you already reloaded the extension? Can you show your full code (either in the question, or on http://pastie.org/ or http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Yes, i've reloaded. Also tried removing and reinstalling the extension.
Here's a link to the file source: http://db.tt/DglZbvyJ

Comment: @theCrius You're including `popup.js` IN THE HEAD. That script is immediately executed, but the `<body>` doesn't even exist yet. To solve that specific problem, wrap your code in a domready event handler: `$(function(){ $('#text').html('Foo!');});` - see http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: you absolutely got the point and i absolutely need to refresh my jquery knowledge. Thanks **a lot** for your time.

Comment: @RobW you write `Content scripts will never run in the context of an extension` - what does this mean exactly? Thx

Comment: @Dan I wrote that statement. The popup that shows up after clicking on the browserAction button is loaded from "chrome-extension://[EXTENSIONID]/popup.html". Content scripts can only be inserted on pages that match a certain [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). `chrome-extension:`-URLs cannot be matched by such patterns (for content scripts), so a content script cannot be run in extension pages, i.e. the context of a Chrome extension. Content scripts will always run in the renderer process of a tab.

Comment: @RobW I have added my <script src> tags within the Head tag, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.("#test").html("Foo!");
```

should be

```
$("#test").html("Foo!");
```

The error you are getting is consistent with this part of the code being incorrect.

Comment: The OP edited his question, so this is not applicable any more. I suggest to edit the answer or delete it.

Comment: But now the error also has changed, so the answer was valid. However, I will append to it.