# How to use jQuery in chrome-extension to open a link?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I build my first Chrome Extensions with code and file snippets below.

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Test",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "First try",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="input1">
    <input id="input2" type="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#input2').click(function(){
             alert('test');
             var whatISearch = $('#input1').val();
             //chrome.tabs.create({'url': "https://www.google.com/search?s=" + whatISearch});
             window.open("https://www.google.com/search?s=" + whatISearch);
        });
    });
```

As you see,what I supposed to do is opening the google search result page in a new window with user search inputs.But unfortunately it doesnt work for me,so is there anything wrong and how can I correct this?

Comment: sorry to missing the selector `#` :-)

Comment: You're referencing the element before it's parsed. Wrap the code in a `$().ready` handler, or move `popup.js` right before `</body>`.

Comment: @RobW Should I choose browser_action or page_action ?

Comment: Depends. If you want the button to always show up, use `browser_action`. If it must only be visible on some pages, use `page_action`.

Comment: @RobW `$().ready(function){
 $('#input2').click(function(){
   var whatISearch = $('#input1').val();
   chrome.tabs.create({'url': "https://www.google.com/search?s=" + whatISearch});
 });
});` Still not working :-(

Comment: `$(function() { .... });` or `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`. See docs for http://api.jquery.com/ready. AND move the declaration of `whatISearch` inside the click handler, and use `.val()` to retrieve the value instead of `.innerText`.

Comment: @RobW I do as what you said,see the question which I just edited,still stuck in trouble.AND `window.open` or `chrome.tabs.create` both not working.

Comment: You did not do everything as I said, you missed "move the declaration of `whatISearch` inside the click handler".

Comment: @RobW sorry 2 bother u so much,but I think as u said in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035242/loading-jquery-into-chrome-extension),the script is immediately executed as the page loaded,so the code inside the `click` handler wont work at all.I try to `alert('something')` but it didnt...

Comment: I assume that you meant [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035242/loading-jquery-into-chrome-extension#comment16066060_12035425). In that Q&A, the code loaded before `</body>`, so that doesn't pose any problems. I've copy-pasted the code from your question, and it works fine. Did you reload your extension after changing the code?

Comment: Yes,i did.It's difficult to tell what is wrong here.Maybe caused by my labtop?I would gratitude ur time for this question.I will check the code tomorrow and would like to pick ur answer as the correct but u just write it in the comments.

Comment: Probably caused by caching. Close Chrome, and start it again. That should work. And/or press Ctrl+Shift+Del and clear the cache.

Comment: There is no question any more, because you've edited it so often that the original issues (missing `#`, not using domready, not using `.val()`, not using `whatISearch` in the click handler) are solved. I suggest to delete the question, since the domready answer has been covered many times, and the rest is probably not of any use to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing # symbols from the beginning of the input IDs, and you're populating `whatISearch` before clicking `input2`, not when you click it.  Try this...

```
$('#input2').click(function(){
    var whatISearch = $('#input1').val();
    window.open("https://www.google.com/search?s=" + whatISearch);
});
```

Also, as `input1` is a text input, use `val()` to get the value, not `innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery id selectors start with a `#` :

```
$('#input1')
```

A solution to check what happens is to use `debugger;` so that you can see what's inside your collection and whether the callback is called :

```
var whatISearch = $('#input1').innerText;
debugger;
$('#input2').click(function(){
     debugger;
     window.open("https://www.google.com/search?s=" + whatISearch);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a tab in a chrome extension you could use `chrome.tabs.create` function:

```
$('#input2').click(function(){
     var whatISearch = $('#input1').val();
     chrome.tabs.create({'url': "https://www.google.com/search?s=" + whatISearch});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Id selector in JQuery work with #, so make correction and use

```
$('#input1').innerText;
```

Also, you are opening a window on click of submit button so read the input1 value inside callback function only like below.

```
$('#input2').click(function(){
     var whatISearch = $('#input1').innerText;
     window.open("https://www.google.com/search?s=" + whatISearch);
});
```