# Chrome extension refusing to load Jquery script / make JSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

A bit of a novice attempting to create my first Chrome extension here. 
I've verified my JQuery and html code to be working by running it via opening it in a browser in a normal .html file that calls the .JS file.

However, the Chrome extension with the same code fails to run, seemingly due to CSP issues. (I am calling the ajax library in my html via https)

```
Refused to load the script
'http://www.reddit.com/r/abandonedporn/.json?jsonp=jQuery111307901595502626151_1438751974832&_=1438751974833'
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"script-src'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js". send @ library.js:5
```

I've modified my manifest.json file with every last thing that I thought necessary, including:

```
{"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/*; object-src 'self'"},

"permissions": [
"http://www.reddit.com/r/abandonedporn/.json?jsonp=?",
"http://www.reddit.com/*", "https://www.reddit.com/*",
"http://www.reddit.com/r/abandonedporn/",
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js/",
"http://www.reddit.com/r/abandonedporn/.json?jsonp=jQuery111309090442832093686_1438671168851&_=1438671168852",
"http://*/*", "https://*/*",
"http://reddit.com/json*",
"http://www.reddit.com/r/abandonedporn/*"],
```

and

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "https://www.google.com/*",
    "http://www.reddit.com/abandonedporn/*"
  ],
  "js": [
    "src/inject/inject.js",
    "src/content.js",
    "src/override/get_pics.js",
    "src/override/get_pics2.js",
    "src/override/library.js"

   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Lastly, my actual Jquery script:
(Note that changing ".getJSON" to ".getScript" did not help.)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  $.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/abandonedporn/.json?jsonp=?",   function(data) { 

$.each(data.data.children, function(i,item){

      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.data.url).appendTo("#images");

      });

   });

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery in chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317476/how-to-use-jquery-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: Zig, I understand your concern but I've followed the comments there and there doesn't seem to be a clear cut answer of how to properly fix the issue.

Comment: but its explained there and the official guides. read about extension permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load external (CDN) script files in chrome extension as per new CSP from google. You need to package all your resources, download jquery and access from your package. "jquery.min.js" instead CDN-URL/jquery.min.js. Here is in [detail](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

Comment: Thanks, so if I wanted to parse pictures from a website such as http://reddit.com/r/pics , is this still possible?

Comment: Will look into apps but will these be able to provide me with the same new-tab modifications that extensions are able to change? Started this to modify the default new-tab action in Chrome

Comment: why do you say extensions cant access web services? yes they can just configure the manifest

Comment: also note there are several duplicates to this answer.

Comment: Zig, could you be a bit more specific when you say "configure the manifest"? I've tried many times and that's why I've posted here. An example would be super helpful.