# import module in web-extensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to build a firefox web-extension and I'd like to import another module (for code reuse) into the popup script. I've looked around and read that import *might* work, but eslint says its a reserved keyword.

I also read where someone recommended to import the second script straight onto the html page like so:

```
<script src="./js/utils/Listeners.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="./js/popup.js"></script>
```

I tried it just like this but didn't get anywhere. Also new to Javascript. Better at more traditionally OOP languages.

Is there a way to import a module into another using web-extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve the problem using jQuery to load scripts/modules, though further testing might be required.

credit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317476/how-to-use-jquery-in-chrome-extension) on loading jQuery into a firefox webextension.