# Using jquery in a js file chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Hi guys i have js file in my chrome extension. is there a way to include jquery and use into it ?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

something like this but in my js file ?

Comment: Did you search this, should have been asked already on here.

Comment: Download jquery.min.js and use it just as any other local script that you write yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery in chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317476/how-to-use-jquery-in-chrome-extension)