# inject brython into a webpage in the content_scripts way

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, brython

I am trying to inject [TextExtractor2.js](https://github.com/redstoneleo/EngkuDictHelper/blob/master/TextExtractor2.js) written in brython into every loaded webpage using the [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#functionality) way,  all my extension  code is [here](https://github.com/redstoneleo/EngkuDictHelper),  but the chrome console shows 
`TextExtractor2.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

So anyone can help ?

Comment: brython patches `<script>` elements in the page so it won't work with content scripts as they are running in an "isolated world". You can try appending an iframe that points to an html file inside your extension (used and declared as shown in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) documentation) so inside that iframe you can write a standard html page and use brython as is (well, you'll probably have to [relax extension CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing) though).

Comment: @wOxxOm I think I am using the same method as that of injecting jquery mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317597/1485853 the way works , but why I failed here? I cannot tell the difference

Comment: Like I said content scripts don't run as `<script>` elements - do you know what this is?

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. As an example, I am going to inject  TextExtractor2.js into every loaded webpage , so does the iframe stuff  you mentioned help ?

Comment: 1) Content scripts are different from normal page scripts so brython can't process them. 2) Using an iframe you can craft a normal html page that brython can process. That iframe will be appended to a web page, and inside the iframe you can display your UI or do other stuff.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks again ! I think I have to specify my aim here. Suppose I want to get the text content from the element I clicked in  every loaded webpage with my Chrome extension, I could work this out via vanilla JavaScript, I wonder whether the same could be achieved with brython, is the brython version porting feasible？

Comment: AFAICT it won't work with content scripts.