# Javascript code suddenly stops when notification appears in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, web-scraping

I am coding a chrome extension to detect changes in the DOM after a certain button is clicked on [this website](https://www.carters.com/carters-baby-boy-tops/V_19125711.html). Specifically, once one clicks the add-to-cart button, a popup appears displaying more information, and when this occurs the DOM changes. I've coded an event listener to see when the add-to-cart button is clicked. However, if I click say one of the buttons to specify my size, a notification in the console appears stating *Overriding "availability.update"!*. And after this, when I click the add-to-cart button, I get no response from my code. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**JavaScript (content.js)**

```
document.getElementById("add-to-cart").addEventListener("click", domChange);  //event listener for add-to-cart button

function domChange(){  //checks for changes in the DOM
    var myElement = $('<div class="modal-content js-modal-content></div>')[0];

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
       if (document.contains(myElement)) {
            console.log("It's in the DOM!");
            observer.disconnect();
        }else{
            console.log('did not work');
        }
    });

    observer.observe(document, {attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree:true});
}
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Extension Test",
    "description": "chrome extension trial build",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
   "content_scripts": [{
     "js": ["content.js"],
     "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
   }],
   

   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js; object-src 'self'",
    "permissions": [
        "http://localhost/",
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]

}
```

**HTML (popup.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `code blocks` instead of italics when representing code or console output that should be formatted like code.

```
`<code stuff>`
```

Also, please provide a git repo/zip file/archive file with the minimum code required for the problem to occur.

Also, since this is run as a Chrome extension, please add the `google-chrome-extension` tag.

## First Error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Using `$(`*something*`)` in JS code usually means you are using jQuery. jQuery is a JS library that is designed to help write JS code. To use `$(`*something*`)`, you will need to load in jQuery.

This means that jQuery is not configured/loaded correctly.

- Your JavaScript file is not being properly loaded into your page
- You have a botched version of jQuery. This could happen because someone edited the core file, or a plugin may have overwritten the $ variable.
- You have JavaScript running before the page is fully loaded, and as such, before jQuery is fully loaded.

Source: [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

But, you did load jQuery in `popup.html`. Why is jQuery not loading?

```html
<!-- popup.html -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`popup.html` is for the popup when you click on the icon. The JS in the popup runs in the context of `popup.html`, not the website.

I changed the code to log `TEST 0` from `content.js`. Notice that `TEST 0` is not shown in the website's DevTools Console, but rather the popup's DevTools Console.

If it's a "normal" webpage:
To load jQuery, use one of these to add a `script` tag to the DOM.

If it's inside a Chromium extension:

`Start of quote`

You have to add your jquery script to your chrome-extension project and to the `background` section of your manifest.json like this :

```
  "background":
    {
        "scripts": ["thirdParty/jquery-2.0.3.js", "background.js"]
    }
```

If you need jquery in a content_scripts, you have to add it in the manifest too:

```
"content_scripts": 
    [
        {
            "matches":["http://website*"],
            "js":["thirdParty/jquery.1.10.2.min.js", "script.js"],
            "css": ["css/style.css"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
```

This is what I did.

Also, if I recall correctly, the background scripts are executed in a background window that you can open via `chrome://extensions`.

`End of quote` Source: [How to use jQuery in chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317476/how-to-use-jquery-in-chrome-extension)

### Popup DevTools

[image: Popup DevTools]

### Website DevTools

[image: Website DevTools]

## Second Error

[image: Error Details]

This error probably means that element `add-to-cart` doesn't exist. But, it does exist in the webpage.

[image: DevTools: Add to Cart button]

The problem is that this runs in the `popup.html` context, not of the website. There is no `add-to-cart` element in `popup.html`.

Do not use `popup.html` to initiate content scripts. Chrome automatically runs them for you on a page if you set the manifest correctly.

[image: content js check]

## Third Error/Warning

`main.js?yocs=35_:1 Overriding "availability.update"!`

This *probably* has nothing to do with `content.js`. This is from `main.js` from a CDN used by `carters.com`, `cdn-fsly.yottaa.net`, which *probably* has nothing to do with your code.

As such, you most likely can't fix this, and doing so might create a security hole.

Implement the changes proposed, and `did not work` appears. This is because you never add the element. Since this question is about the response from code, and I think `did not work` is a response, I think this solves the problem.
[image: Website DevTools]

Question and Answer available here using SSH:
`git@gitlab.com:colourdelete/so-question-63801721.git`
Using HTTPS:
`https://gitlab.com/colourdelete/so-question-63801721.git`