# how to get reference to current tab of current window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am a newbie for Google Chrome Extensions development ,I wonder how to get a reference to the current tab of current window .

I used `chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}` but it doesn't work when multiple windows opened .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the currently opened tab's URL in my page action popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413911/how-to-get-the-currently-opened-tabs-url-in-my-page-action-popup)

Answer (score 8):

Every window that has a tab has one `active` tab, so if there are multiple windows open, you need to specify which window you want.

To get the window that the current script is calling from, use:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT }, function (tabs) {
    // Do something with tabs
});
```

If, however, by "current window", you mean the front-most focused window shown to the user, use:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    // Do something with tabs
});
```

For further info, see [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) and [Chrome's definition of current window](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#the-current-window).

Comment: This answer is missing the callback in the `query` method.

Comment: Is the topmost window and focused window the same ?

Comment: @user1485853 Pretty sure, yes.