# Chrome Extension ContextMenu for PDF

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a extension for the chrome browser and i want to add a specified contextmenu for pdf documents. I also add to specified contextmenus for the type "page" and "image".
If i set the type to "all" then there is a contextmenu, but not specified for pdf documents.

Is it possible to add a specified contextmenu for pdf documents or should i use a the type "all" an it make switch case in the clickEventHandler?!

See more at:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html

These are the "file" types:

```
contexts ( optional array of enum of "all", "page", "frame", "selection", "link", "editable", "image", "video", "audio", or "launcher" )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to add a context menu only when a PDF is shown in a tab, right? Just asking because I thought at first that you wanted to add the context menu on links to PDF files, which is indeed possible*. (as you probably know)

I couldn't find a way to do this directly, however one alternative could be to listen to [`chrome.tabs.onActivated`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated) and add or remove your context menu based on if the current URL matches a PDF file. One drawback is that it means asking for the `tabs` permission which might looks scary to users. ("This extension can access your tabs and browsing activity" or something like that)

*for the curious, you do it like this:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Hello world",
    contexts: ["link"],
    targetUrlPatterns: ["*://*/*.pdf"]
});
```

(you would add the other options that interest you of course)

Comment: Thank you, i modified my function, and now the specified context menu works only for pdf documents:

Comment: Just curious, does this still work as of today, given that the out-of-process pdf extension behaves very different?

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't work with `'documentUrlPatterns': ["*://*/*.pdf"]`

Answer (score 3):

This functions works for me for pdf documents:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (info) {
    var tab = chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, function (tab) {
        if (tab.url.indexOf(".pdf") > 0) {
            chrome.contextMenus.create({
                "id": "1",
                title: "Just for PDF Documents",
                contexts: ["all"],
                onclick: function (e) {
                }
            });
        } else {
            chrome.contextMenus.remove("1", null);
        }
    });
});
```

Maybe the line

```
if (tab.url.indexOf(".pdf") > 0) {
```

should edit with a expression!

Answer (score 0):

Current answers are not perfect:

1. The way to remove context menus
2. Not work well with new open pdf file or multiple windows

   ```
   let g_contextMenus = [{
       id: "test",
       title: "test"
   }];

   function createContextMenus() {

   for (var menu of g_contextMenus) {
       chrome.contextMenus.create({
           id: menu["id"],
           type: "normal",
           title: menu["title"],
           contexts: ["all"]
       });
       }
   }
   createContextMenus();

   function updateContextMenu(tabId) {
       chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) {
           var suffix = tab.url.slice(-4);
           var isPdf = suffix.toLowerCase() == ".pdf";
           for (var menu of g_contextMenus) {
               chrome.contextMenus.update(menu["id"], { visible: isPdf })
           }
       });
   };

   /**
    * Switch tab
    **/
   chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(info) {
       updateContextMenu(info.tabId);
   });

   /**
    * New open file
    **/
   chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
       var suffix = tab.url.slice(-4);
       if (info.status == "complete" && suffix.toLowerCase() == ".pdf") {
           updateContextMenu(tabId);
       }
   });

   /**
    * Multiple window/New window
    **/
   chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(winId) {
       chrome.tabs.query({ lastFocusedWindow: true, active: true }, function(tabs) {
           updateContextMenu(tabs[0].id);
       });
   });
   ```

References:

1. [How to get the currently opened tab's URL in my page action popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413911/how-to-get-the-currently-opened-tabs-url-in-my-page-action-popup)
2. [Check if Item is already in the Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000136/check-if-item-is-already-in-the-context-menu)