# Detecting whether a page is https or not in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to come-up with a way that, when the pop-up button of a Chrome Extension is clicked, the extension checks whether the current tab is https.

If it is, display an alert and then break or don't run the next function.
If it isn't, then do nothing (as in, don't display the alert and run the extension normally)

I tried

```
if (window.location.protocol === 'https:') {
 alert("NO");
```

In the popup.js but it doesn't seem to be working. Variations either just display the popup somehwere in the corner and the extension keeps working, or nothing happens.

Is there an inherent way of doing this with the Chrome API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the currently opened tab's URL in my page action popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413911/how-to-get-the-currently-opened-tabs-url-in-my-page-action-popup)

Comment: The duplicate question is about getting the URL for a given tab. If you know how to do thst, it's trivial to determine whether the string starts with https. E.g. `if (url.indexOf('https:') === 0) { ... }`.

Comment: So would I need to make use of chrome.tabs.query or can I just implement `if (url.indexOf('https:') === 0) { ... }`? How would such a solution look? Is it possible to integrate it into the popup.js?

Comment: Ok so I managed to get it working with your help and the help of the other question. All I need is an alert, so after the `if (url.indexOf('https:') === 0) { ... }` I setup an alert. Problem is, the alert is not centered (top right corner instead) and the extension still continues to run afterwards. I don't mind the pop-up opening, but I'd like no other functions to run if this alert is displayed. Basically, if the page is https, alert me and break.