# How to pass url from background.js to popup.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, runtime

I can't find any working code since getSelected is depreciated. But can anyone help me with how to achieve this?

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab: chrome.tabs.Tab) => {
  const urlTab: string = tab.url as string;
  console.log(urlTab)
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo: chrome.tabs.TabActiveInfo) => {
  const tabId: number = activeInfo.tabId;
  chrome.tabs.get(tabId, (tab: chrome.tabs.Tab) => {
    const urlTab: string = tab.url as string;
    console.log(urlTab)
  });
});
```

If I have this in background.js, how can I pass the urlTab in popup.js?
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: chrome.action.onClicked won't work if your popup is defined in default_popup. Simply query the tab in your popup script directly: [How to get the currently opened tab's URL in my page action popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10413911)

Comment: Im using manifest v3 and `runtime.getBackgroundPage()` not available .

Comment: You don't need it.