# chrome.tabs.query not returning correct tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension that submits links to an aggregation website. In order to do this, I need to get the URL from the currently open window, which I'm trying to do with this code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    ...
});
```

This works fine with only one window open, but it seems to select the active tab from the first opened window when I have more than one open, rather than from the last focused window. I have tried using currentWindow also, but that seems to have the same problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I had 2 versions of my extension: one with the unpacked files and one packed as a .crx file. I was updating the unpacked code, but the version I was loading in my browser was the already packed one. So of course my changes weren't being reflected. Solved by making sure I was testing using the unpacked version.

Comment: Consider deleting your question, or edit it such that this answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems very similar [to the one below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2797972/2002095), please have a look.

Useful code sample from question:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = tab.url; });
```

Also note the section about

> Inline scripts and event handlers disallowed

(in Chrome extensions)

Hopefully that puts you on the right track!

Edited for my poor formatting and unfamiliarity with SO formating.

Comment: "Note: All answers here are suggesting to use `chrome.tabs.getSelected`. This API method has been deprecated though, you have to use `chrome.tabs.query` instead - See [How to get the currently opened tab's URL in my page action popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413911/how-to-get-the-currently-opened-tabs-url-in-my-page-action-popup/10417327#10417327)" – [Rob W Aug 29 '12 at 9:56](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797853/get-url-and-save-it-chrome-extension/2797972#comment16297324_2797853)